# PyMySql in AWS Lambda - Connection Reset By Peer

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, aws-lambda, pymysql

I am currently trying to query a Sql Server back in our On-premise environment using the PyMySql python library within AWS Lambda.

All I am attempting to do is create my connection object using the following code:

```
import pymysql

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    conn = pymysql.connect(
        host = 'MYSERVER',
        port = 1433,
        user = 'acctname',
        passwd = 'acctpass',
        db = 'dbName'
    )
```

I can't even get past this without the following error message:

```
(2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query ([Errno 104] Connection reset by peer)')
```

I can confirm the port and credentials are correct.

I am hoping this is not a limitation of lambda within AWS. If any other services or libraries are available that I can leverage from Lambda for SQL Server, please let me know!

**EDIT:** My lambda is running in a VPC that is connected to my on-premis environment.

Comment: Is the Lambda function configured to run inside a VPC? Also, is there a firewall in front of your on-prem server that needs to be opened?

Comment: I should have mentioned, yes my lambda is running inside a VPC. And no, there should not be a firewall inn front of the on-prem db. I am verifying that now.

Answer (score 0):

For an AWS Lambda function running inside a VPC to access anything outside the VPC, it must be in a private subnet of the VPC that contains a route to a NAT gateway. Lambda functions inside a VPC do not get a public IP address, so you must provide Internet access via NAT.